# What is the intended way to run functions after a state change in React? (not including initial render)

Tags: reactjs

Is there an intended way to execute a function after a setState() function is finished? For example

```
const TestComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null)

  const apiRequest = async () => {
    const reply = await fetch(`/api/${value}`)
    const response = await reply.json()
    console.log(response)
  }

  const handleClick = async () => {
    setValue(value + 1)
    apiRequest(value)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Call API</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Say I have this component, I want to click a button and hit an API. Of course apiRequest will not use the right value for the `value` state. Assuming I do want to use the right value, is there any way to preserve this flow but do it in a way that works? I know I can use useEffect, but let's assume I don't want to do this logic every time `value` changes.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` (or `useLayoutEffect`) *is* the best and most reliable way to do this by far - don't be afraid of using it if it suits the task. If you don't want to use it for some reason, the only other decent way would be to put the new state value into a variable and pass it around as needed - but this will require functions that use it to use the argument(s), and not use the outer state variables.

```
const apiRequest = async (value) => {
  const reply = await fetch(`/api/${value}`)
  const response = await reply.json()
  console.log(response)
}

const handleClick = async () => {
  const newValue = value + 1;
  setValue(newValue)
  apiRequest(newValue)
}
```

Comment: I was worried that was the answer. 

I always have 2 big issues with useEffect that I can't seem to get past. For one, I don't know how to use it to run functions conditionally. For example if I had multiple handleClick functions that all rely on `value` but use different api calls. Assuming I'm supposed to put my `apiRequest` function in useEffect, how would I be able to determine which request to run?

My other question is about initial render. useEffect will run on the initial page render all the time right? What if I only want to run my `apiRequest` method  after an action is done.

Comment: (1) You could set some state to indicate which API call needs to be made when clicking. `setValue(newValue); setClickType('foo'); }` (2) Have another state that checks whether the component is mounted yet, and if not, do nothing. `useEffect(() => setMounted(true), [])` and you can check the `mounted` state